# Android build error Cannot compute meet of types: FLOAT and INT

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I just upgraded Android Studio from 3.3 canary 5 to canary 8.

The update required to change the `'com.android.tools.build:gradle'` dependency to 3.3.0-alpha08.
And now build fails in the `':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'` task with the error:

Caused by: `com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Cannot compute meet of types: FLOAT and INT`

I have absolutely no clue what went wrong, can anyone please assist with this issue?

Comment: It's highly likely this is caused by a bug, as a result of you using a _Canary_ build of Android Studio.

Comment: @TheWanderer I ended up reverting back to 3.3.0-alpha06 which fixed the issue. Thank you for the help!